# Rails + CKEditor + Paperclip + AWS S3 to upload files in different folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, paperclip

I was able to set up CKEditor to allow editing of `Article` model in my Rails app, and it will upload any images to AWS S3 via Paperclip. The upload is successful.

However, all the images uploaded are not separated into folders. This will cause problems when my app eventually has many many articles.

For example, to edit a picture in any one of the articles, the user will have to scroll through the whole list of pictures, even those pictures that does not belong to the article of contention, just to find the correct one.

Is there a way to upload the images in an organised manner, like namespacing according to each `article`'s `title` or `id`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

YOu can try something like--

```
has_attached_file :picture,
  :storage => :s3,
  :bucket => 'your_bucket',
  :path => "#{Rails.env}/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename.:extension"
```

you can pass the bucket name and the path for your bucket will be *my_bucket_name/development/image/1/thumbnail/my_thumbnail.jpg*

i believe you can also call method or block in :bucket to dynamically handle the names of the folder..something like-

```
...
:bucket => get_folders,
...
...

###somewhere in model.rb
def get_folders
 if self.type = 'Admin'
   "admin"
 else
   "user"
end
```

You can **access** it like any other model object -

```
@picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
###url of the picture
url = @picture.my_attachment_name.url
##considering above scenario,where picture is attachment name
url = @picture.picture.url
```

you can give this a try.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Milind, how can I access this in the ckeditor window?

Comment: you can access it like @picture.attachment.url..see my updated answer...